# How to create this advanced Kotlin function?

Tags: function, kotlin

I am looking to create a custom function like this:

```
customFunction(arg1, arg2, arg3, etc.){
     doSomethingIfConditionIsAccomplished()
}
```

, where the function accepts `vararg` as a parameter so you can add as many arguments as you like and the function `doSomethingIfConditionIsAccomplished()` thats's inside brackets is run only if a certain condition in the function is verified, like:

If (arg1 > arg2 > arg3) -> allow `doSomethingIfConditionIsAccomplished()` function to run otherwise nothing happens.

The function should look something like:

```
private fun <T: Any> customFunction(vararg input: T?){
    -condition-
}
```

Comment: `if (arg1 > arg2 > arg3)` be more specific, this makes no sense with a `T: Any`

Answer (score 0):

Since vararg is just an array inside the function, you can do something like this:

```
private fun <T: Comparable<T>> customFunction(vararg input: T){
    val condition = (1 until input.size).none { input[it] < input[it-1] }
    if(condition) {
        println("calling doSomethingIfConditionIsAccomplished()")
    } else {
        println("not calling doSomethingIfConditionIsAccomplished()")
    }
}

fun main() {
    customFunction(1,2,3) // -> calling doSomethingIfConditionIsAccomplished()
    customFunction(2,1,3) // -> not calling doSomethingIfConditionIsAccomplished()
}
```

But this way the condition is hard-coded, and the `T` must be `Comparable<T>`. There's no point in writing methods like this, except you want to implement `Strategy` pattern but that's slightly different.